# Microsoft SQL alternative for Oracle's Imp and Exp command

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, export, import

I'm looking a command line tool or SQL command to export/import a table or complete database. Much like the imp and exp commands of Oracle databases.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [bcp utility](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/how-do-i-use-bcp-in-sql-server/319) (bulk copy).

It only does a table at a time, but [here is a script](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/brettk/archive/2004/06/17/1618.aspx) that will do the entire thing.

As for a single command to export an entire database, it appears from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511851/is-there-any-single-sql-command-to-export-entire-database-from-one-sql-server-to) that it is not possible.